# wpf textbox flat border style

Tags: wpf, textbox, styles

need to have flat border style for wpf based textbox... really surprised to see there is no easy way to get this like was in winforms textbox BorderStyle.FixedSingle

is there any easy way to get this done for wpf textbox

Answer (score 19):

The way to do this is to use a control template to draw the border yourself.  You can do this in many different ways, heres a couple for you to look at.

The quick hack approach:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle  Stroke="{StaticResource ResourceKey=detailMarkBrush}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                <TextBox Margin="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" BorderThickness="0"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

and then theres using resources...

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Color x:Key="detailMark">#FFA1A9B3</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="detailMarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource ResourceKey=detailMark}" />
    <Style x:Key="flatTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle  Stroke="{StaticResource ResourceKey=detailMarkBrush}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                        <TextBox Margin="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" BorderThickness="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and then you can use the style:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=flatTextBox}" />
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<TextBox BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
```

just try this by black or gray

Comment: This only appears to work whilst the textbox is not focused.  When it gets the focus, the border is highlighted with two blue shades.

Answer (score 3):

This is better way to me, make a custom template with border, to override the default one.

And most important make `ScrollViewer` named `PART_ContentHost`, to fit inner `TemplatePart`, and for any other features work like default.

simular to example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <Border CornerRadius="2" Padding="2" Background="#19212F" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```