# TextBox doesn't have BorderStyle Property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to create a TextBox that is selectable but looks like a label. Other [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444565/how-can-i-have-selectable-labels) have talked about setting the BorderStyle to `None` in order to hide the TextBox look and feel. Why can't I access the BorderStyle from my Xaml? I'm using the MVVM design pattern.

[image]

Comment: have you looked at [MSDN Border.BorderThickness Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.borderthickness(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BorderStyle` exists only in `WinForms` while `WPF` uses `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush`

The simplest way would be this:

```
<TextBox BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" />
```

For more customization, you could override the `ControlTemplate`, for example described in this post: [wpf textbox flat border style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475086/wpf-textbox-flat-border-style)

*By the way*: It could be confusing for the user, if a control looks totally different than the way it looks in most applications.